# How to implement the SKI combinator calculus with match types?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, scala-3, dotty, match-types

I was trying to implement the [SKI combinator calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus) in Dotty using match types.

A quick description of the SKI combinator calculus:

- `S`, `K`, and `I` are terms
- `(xy)` is a term if `x` and `y` are terms and is like function application
- `(((Sx)y)z)` (same as`Sxyz`) returns `xz(yz)` (same as `(xz)(yz)`)
- `((Kx)y)` (same as `Kxy`) returns `x`
- `(Ix)` returns `x`

Below is what I used (`R` reduces the term as much as possible). A term `(xy)` is written as a tuple `(x,y)`, and `S`, `K`, and `I` are traits.

```
trait S
trait K
trait I

type R[T] = T match {
  case (((S,x),y),z) => R[((x,z),(y,z))]
  case ((K,x),y) => R[x]
  case (I,x) => R[x]
  case (a,b) => R[a] match {
    case `a` => (a, R[b])
    case _ => R[(R[a], R[b])]
  }
  case T => T
}
```

However, the following 2 lines don't compile (both for the same reason) ([Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Y7UkCvmfQv6DMcyw1slJKA)):

```
val check: (K, K) = ??? : R[(((S,I),I),K)]
val check2: (K, K) = ??? : R[((I,K),(I,K))]
```

The error says that it required `(K,K)` but found `R[((I, K), (I, K))]`. I expected it first see the S and turn it into `(IK)(IK)`, or `R[((I,K),(I,K))]`, after which it should match the evaluation of the first `(I, K)` and see that it is `K`, which is not the same as `(I, K)`, making it return `R[(R[(I,K)], R[(I,K)])]`, which becomes `R[(K,K)]`, which becomes just `(K,K)`.

However, it doesn't go beyond `R[((I,K),(I,K))]`. Apparently, it does not reduce the term if it's nested. This is odd, because I tried the same approach but with an actual runtime function, and it appears to work properly ([Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/CcDfDhlGSXG2cNjIZflctQ)).

```
case object S
case object K
case object I

def r(t: Any): Any = t match {
  case (((S,x),y),z) => r(((x,z),(y,z)))
  case ((K,x),y) => r(x)
  case (I,x) => r(x)
  case (a,b) => r(a) match {
    case `a` => (a, r(b))
    case c => (c, r(b))
  }
  case _ => t
}
```

The output from `println(r((((S, I), I), K)))` is `(K,K)`, as expected.

Interestingly enough, removing the rule for `K` lets it compile, but it doesn't recognize `(K, K)` and `R[(K, K)]` as the same type. Perhaps this is what is causing the problem? ([Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/u2sZFwtxQs246OVYR5jQCw))

```
def check2: (K, K) = ??? : R[(K, K)]
//Found:    R[(K, K)]
//Required: (K, K)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`S`, `K`, and `I` are not disjoint. The intersections `K with I` etc. are inhabited:

```
println(new K with I)
```

In a match type, a case is only skipped when the types are *disjoint*. So, e.g. this fails:

```
type IsK[T] = T match {
  case K => true 
  case _ => false
}
@main def main() = println(valueOf[IsK[I]])
```

because the `case K => _` branch cannot be skipped, since there are values of `I` that *are* `K`s. So, e.g. in your case `R[(K, K)]` gets stuck on `case (I, x) => _`, since there *are* some `(K, K)`s that are also `(I, x)`s (e.g. `(new K with I, new K {})`). You never get to the `case (a,b) => _`, which would take us to `(K, K)`.

You can make `S`, `K`, and `I` `class`es, which makes them disjoint, since you can't inherit from two `class`es at once.

```
class S
class K
class I

type R[T] = T match {
  case (((S,x),y),z) => R[((x,z),(y,z))]
  case ((K,x),y) => R[x]
  case (I,x) => R[x]
  case (a,b) => R[a] match {
    case `a` => (a, R[b])
    case _ => R[(R[a], R[b])]
  }
  case T => T
}

@main def main(): Unit = {
  println(implicitly[R[(K, K)] =:= (K, K)])
  println(implicitly[R[(((S,I),I),K)] =:= (K, K)])
}
```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/3OfSmqiXSXCdO0OV3e4qGQ)

Another solution is making them all singleton types:

```
object S; type S = S.type
object K; type K = K.type
object I; type I = I.type
// or, heck
type S = 0
type K = 1
type I = 2
```

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. It totally fixes the problem, but it's a little confusing. I thought when you matched on a type, it only worried about *that* type and not its hypothetical descendants. Thanks for the answer

Comment: That would basically mean that match types are only useful on final classes and singleton types?

Comment: @Jasper-M Oh, I've made a mistake. Dotty understands single inheritance, so it works to just have `S`, `K`, and `I` non-final `class`es, since you can't inherit two classes somehow. As you can see, `match` does work for non-final classes, then.